# Create a 2D array of pointers to linked lists in C

Tags: c, arrays, list, pointers, linked-list

i want to create a programm which:

1. Creates a 2D array consisting of pointers to a linked list which contains an integer named result and a *next pointer
2. sets at first all the elements of the array to NULL
3. Then, for every position (i,j) of the array, reads via scanf an integer named temp.If temp==-1 proceeds to the next {i,j} ,if temp!=-1, puts temp into result, creates a NULL list to be the next of `array[i][j]` ,and while given new values for temp does the same work enlarging the list of `array[i][j]`.

I came up writing this code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<malloc.h>

    typedef struct linked_list *list;

    struct linked_list
    {
int result;
list next;
    };

    int main()
    {
int i,j;
scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);

int l,k;
list **array=malloc(i*sizeof(list));

for(l=0;l<j;l++)
    array[l]=malloc(j*sizeof(list));

for(l=0;l<i;l++)
{   
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
        array[i][j]=NULL;
    }
}

int temp;
list new;
list current;
for(l=0;l<i;l++)
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        while(temp!=-1)
        {
            if (array[l][k]==NULL)
            {
                new->result=temp;
                new->next=NULL;
                array[l][k]->next=new;
            }
            else
            {
                current->result=temp;
                current->next=NULL;
                new->next=current;
            }
            scanf("%d",&temp);
        }
    }

int cnt=0;
for(l=0;l<i;l++)
    for(k=0;k<j;k++)
    {
        if (array[l][k]==NULL)
            printf("array(%d)(%d) is empty!\n",l,k);
        else
        {
            do
            {
                cnt++;
                printf("element no.%d of array(%d)(%d) is:   %d\n",cnt,l,k,array[l][k]->result);
                array[l][k]=array[l][k]->next;
            }while (array[l][k]!=NULL);
        }
    }

return 0;
    }
```

Which is intended to do what i described earlier. However, not being very flexible using correctly memory allocation, when running this code even for i=1,j=1 i get "Segmentation fault" as an output. If anyone could help me understand what i have to do in order to allocate correctly the memory required, i would be really glad!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a start, `array[i][j]=NULL;` is clearly wrong

Comment: And with what do i have to replace it?

Comment: you can replace it with arrap[i][j]=-1 for example

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues here to start with.

First, your malloc statements to create the 2D array are wrong.

Your first should be:

```
list **array=(list**)malloc(i*sizeof(list*));
```

Your second should also be changed to below. Note that your for loop conditions were incorrect - you need to use the row dimension (i) in your condition, not j:

```
for(l=0;l<i;l++)
    array[l]=(list*)malloc(j*sizeof(list));
```

That should give you an empty array. Your next task was to set all these elements to NULL. That's where you encounter your next problem.

```
for(l=0;l<i;l++){   
    for(k=0;k<j;k++){
        array[i][j]=NULL;
    }
}
```

Do you see it? You are using the variables "i" and "j" to lookup the element instead of "l" and "k". That's a simple fix.

Now you should have an array of NULL pointers. Great. But now you will find you are getting a different seg fault. This one will be due to this code:

```
if (array[l][k]==NULL){
    new->result=temp;
    new->next=NULL;
    array[l][k]->next=new;
}
```

Notice that you are executing this code if the pointer in the array location is NULL. You then proceed to dereference this same pointer. But that pointer is NULL. Thus, seg fault. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are doing here, you can fix this by changing the last statement to

```
array[l][k] = new;
```

I think this should get you on the right track. Your code still has some problems (check the output for loop...especially the do-while loop), but no more seg faults hopefully.